# Post save signal en Django y relación One to Many

Tags: django

Tengo estos dos modelos:

```
class Evento(models.Model):
    #atributos
    especial = models.BooleanField(...)

class Ocurrencia(models.Model):
    #atributos
    evento = models.ForeingKey(Evento, ...)
    correo_usuario = models.Charfield(...)
```

Cuando se inserta un evento especial por primera vez quiero notificarle a los usuarios de las ocurrencias. Por tanto decidí usar el signal `post_save` de esta manera:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Evento)
def notificar_evento_especial(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.especial and created:
        ocurrencias = Ocurrencia.objects.filter(evento = instance)
        involucrados = []
        for o in ocurrencias:
            involucrados.append[o.correo_usuario]
        email = EmailMessage('Notificacion', 'Evento especial creado', 'correo@ejemplo.com', involucrados)
        email.send()
```

En mi sistema, cuando se inserta un evento a continuación se insertan las ocurrencias del mismo, es por eso que cuando se inserte un evento especial quiero notificarle a los usuarios de las ocurrencias.

Sucede que cuando se ejecuta este signal, él reconoce el evento que se está insertando pero no halla ninguna ocurrencia asociada al evento, por tanto no envía ningún correo. Me imagino que esto se debe a que en el momento que se ejecuta el `save` de Evento no se ha ejecutado todavia el `save` de Ocurrencia, por tanto no existen ocurrencias en la base de datos.

¿Cómo puedo notificarle a los usuarios de las ocurrencias que se ha insertado un evento especial, si solamente se ejecuta el `save` de Evento y no el de Ocurrencia?

Pensé en usar el `post_save` de Ocurrencia pero no sé cómo determinar si el Evento de esa ocurrencia fue creado o modificado.

Comment: por favor, añade tu views para ver como manejas esto.

Comment: creo que la linea `ocurrencias = Ocurrencia.objects.filter(evento = instance)` esta mal , no deberia ser evento__pk = tu id?

Comment: @JackNavaRow en ese caso instance es el objeto Evento que se inserta, por tanto puedo comparar directamente como ves en el codigo.

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila Mis views son my complejos y largos como para ponerlos aqui. Lo que te puedo decir es que recibo los datos del evento a partir de una peticion REST, inserto el evento y con los datos del evento insertado procedo a crear las ocurrencias directamente.

Comment: @Ethan puedes hacer es modificar el metodo `save` del modelo ocurrencia, donde compruebe el boolean `evento.especial` y si es `true` pues lo añades a una lista y mandas el correo, asi estas seguro de que tu modelo ha sido creado

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila estoy usando signals porque el metodo save esta muy sobrecargado (producto de complicaciones con la logica del negocio), de lo contrario hubiese hecho lo que sugieres

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila Al final tuve que modificar el save de Evento para poder resolver mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

despues de intentar varias cosas al final tuve que modificar el metodo `save` de mi modelo `Evento`, como habia sugerido [@ReinierHernándezÁvila](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7656/reinier-hern%C3%A1ndez-%C3%81vila) en su comentario y como ademas lei en la Internet.

Lo que sucede es que cuando se ejecutaba el signal `post_save` de `Evento` no se ejecutaba el de `Ocurrencia`. Esa es la razon por la cual esta linea en mi signal

```
ocurrencias = Ocurrencia.objects.filter(evento = instance)
```

no se ejecutaba, porque en ese momento solo se habia insertado un evento pero ninguna ocurrencia.

Por tanto, en el `save()` de `Evento` agregue una condicion para que cuando fuera un evento especial se notificara por correo a los usuarios.

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, puedes ejecutar `instance.save(commit=False)` para crear la instancia pero no guardarla en la base de datos y después crear la ocurrencia con el signal